# Comma after ᴀɴᴅ before "for instance"?

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases

I need help with this sentence:

> Thus, heat pumps can(,) for instance(,) run whenever there is a high generation of PV electricity(,) or there is a need to increase the electrical load in the grid.

So basically there are three commas that I am unsure about. I would tend to use them. Should I?

Comment: "for instance" is a parenthetical.  It's presence is not need for syntactic and semantic validity.  Parentheticals are typically set off by commas.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks for your answer. So you would say that all three commas are okay?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "in fact" always set off by commas mid-sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154464/is-in-fact-always-set-off-by-commas-mid-sentence) (There are many other threads dealing with parentheticals also. [Brackets with parentheticals](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100603/usage-of-brackets-parentheses/100623#100623) may be helpful, mentioning zero punctuation instead of offsetting commas, a possibility here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use the last comma, although it is possible to use it, and I'd either suppress one  ellipsis or use one more (rather this latter possibility).

- "Thus, heat pumps can, for instance, run whenever there is a high generation of PV electricity or whenever there is a need to increase the electical load in the grid".
- "Thus, heat pumps can, for instance, run whenever there is a high generation of PV electricity) or  a need to increase the electical load in the grid".